# Propagating Calling Context GCC Preprocessor Macro Values to Target Function

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, header-files

Let's say I have

```
foo () {
  bar ();
}
```

where `foo` lies in `f.c` and `bar` lies in `b.c`, i.e. `b.h` is included in `f.c`. I would like to modify `bar` to print that it was called from any function `foo` that invokes it, like so:

```
bar () {
  printf ("Called from line %d in file %s",?,?);
  /* Run as usual */
}
```

I want to obtain these two pieces of information from the [predefined GCC preprocessor macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`. However, these obviously evaluate to the line of `printf` in `b.c` and the path to `b.c` respectively, if simply plugged into the `printf`.

Can I somehow propagate the values of `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` from the calling context to the `printf` in `bar`, so "Called from line x in file foo.c" is printed instead?

I attempted to rename `bar` to `bar2` and then define a delegator function in the header file `b.h`:

```
bar () {
  printf ("Called from line %d in file %s",__LINE__,__FILE__);
  bar2 ();
}
```

The idea was that the `#include` directive would copy the header code into the source file `f.c` and then substitute the path to `f.c` and line number respectively. However, this gave me a duplicate definition error across the different translation units.

Next, I tried to add the `static` modifier to the header definition of `bar2` to allow multiple definitions. I can then compile without errors and run the program, but still only `bar.h` is printed.

Where am I going wrong? I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

Questions:

1. Why not just use a debugger like GDB? This is kernel code.
2. Why not do caller-side debugging? Large code base.

EDIT:

Why does this not work?

```
#ifdef DEBUG_PALLOC
#define palloc_get_page(FLAGS) (palloc_get_page_debug (FLAGS,  __FILE__,__LINE__))
#else
void *palloc_get_page (enum palloc_flags);
#endif
```

Comment: You will have to pass it as a parameter. OT: Do you know what FAQ means?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Replaced FAQ with Questions.
Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me why this is not possible? Can I not have local definitions of the function everywhere it is included which then point to global symbols after printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a delegate, but not a function in the `.h` as `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` would be in the `.h` (and the `static` modifier doesn't help here), but with a *macro* which will expand at the proper location with the correct file & line info.

```
#define bar2() bar(__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

and `bar` should accept file & line parameters:

```
void bar(const char *file, int line)
{
   printf ("Called from line %d in file %s",line,file);
}
```

The gdb method is more complex. That could work with:

- a gdb script that prints the current breakpoint location / traceback and continues,
- a collaborating `bar` function that triggers a breakpoint (On intel/Windows: with the `Breakpoint` function or `asm("int $3")` directive, if a flag/env. var is set telling that the debugger is enabled, but if `bar` is called often, this could slow down the program a lot)

Note: if you want to make it activable or not, this is becoming more complex, but by setting a command line `-DDEBUG` flag you could make the following print the lines or not:

file `bar.h`:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef DEBUG

#define bar2() bar(__FILE__,__LINE__)
void bar(const char *file, int line);

#else
void bar2();
#endif
```

file `bar.c`

```
#include "bar.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
void bar(const char *file, int line)
#else
void bar2()
#endif

{
#ifdef DEBUG
   printf ("Called from line %d in file %s\n",line,file);
#endif
   printf("NOP\n");
}
```

call `bar2` from your main program. If `DEBUG` is set, `bar2` is a macro that calls `bar`. If `DEBUG` isn't set, `bar2` is directly your function.

Note that doing that for all your functions is tedious, unless you use a script to generate those patterns.

Comment: Awesome! Will try this ASAP. For educational purposes though, why does using the `static` keyword to allow multiple definitions not work here?

Comment: it doesn't for the same reason: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` refer to the original file they are included from. Only macros are able to make that dynamic.

Comment: yes, define only the macro, but don't define the function prototype afterwards as it will expand

Comment: Wow, was about to move the question to the OP, since the formatting was way off, but you're insanely fast. Thanks for the reply, it makes sense, but then how can I make the replacement conditional? I'd like to use the regular function if a debugging flag is not defined. Previously I threw an `#ifdef` around the `#define`, but now if the debugging flag is not set, the function won't be declared in the header at all, right?

Comment: in the header only perform the `#define` statements if a flag is set, else define a regular `bar` function , that would work, provided you also use `#ifdef` on the file/line arguments in the case of a non-debug. I hope you can make sense of all this.

Comment: Something like `#ifdef DEBUG #define foo() #else void *foo() #endif` gives me the same `expected declaration specifiers before constant` error. Should I use a `#define` in the alternative as well?

Comment: For the most part, still a bit confused by "provided you also use `#ifdef` on the file/line arguments in the case of a non-debug." In my code the file/line arguments are discarded in the case of a non-debug. I updated the OP, because it's probably clearer if you can see the code.

Comment: It works now, I forgot to make the actual function definitions in the C file conditional as well. Thanks for all the effort you put into this, have a nice evening! Definitely took something away from this.